# handling error 502 with python post request

Tags: post, python-requests, try-catch

trying to build a simple script to download data with multiple post requests.
sometimes I get an error due to Response [504].

I tried some try/except to handle this error but somehow I'm not catching the event

I attached the code without the exception handling and a picture of the error.
I know that the error is from JSON because there is no data to decode due to the bad response error

any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
import os
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
b = []
current_max = 0
print("downloading first 100 rows data for contract betdiceadmin")
data = {"pos": str(current_max), "offset": "100", "account_name" : "betdiceadmin"}    
request = requests.post(" https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_actions", json=data)   
print(request)
jsonObj = request.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(jsonObj['actions']))
print("finished downloding rows " + str(current_max) +  " to " + str(max(df.account_action_seq)))
b.append(df)
current_max +=100


while max(df.account_action_seq) >= current_max:    
    print("current maximum is "+str(max(df.account_action_seq)))
    time.sleep(5)
    data = {"pos": str(current_max+1), "offset": "99", "account_name" : "betdiceadmin"}
    request = requests.post(" https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_actions", json=data)
    print(request)
    jsonObj = request.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(jsonObj['actions']))
    current_max +=100
    b.append(df)
    print("max from df is :" + str(max(df.account_action_seq)))


df3 = pd.concat(b, sort=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got `JSONDecodeError`, because of your `50x` response content is not JSON. So you should run `request.json()` when you get 200, if not, try again and wait a bit longer. btw do not add space in url.

```
while max(df.account_action_seq) >= current_max:    
    print("current maximum is "+str(max(df.account_action_seq)))
    time.sleep(5)
    data = {"pos": str(current_max+1), "offset": "99", "account_name" : "betdiceadmin"}
    request = requests.post("https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_actions", json=data , verify=False)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        jsonObj = request.json()
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(jsonObj['actions']))
        current_max +=100
        b.append(df)
        print("max from df is :" + str(max(df.account_action_seq)))
    else:
        print("try to post again")
        continue
```